# How to dynamically display different reactive forms in an Angular component?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am looking to set up task-based UI in my project. I want to separate one form into multiple smaller forms so that you can edit one part at a time. The user should be able to click on one part of the object, which will open an Angular dialog, and the project will dynamically insert that form into the dialog (using ngFor to iterate over all the controls, wsince there are different controls for each form). For example, I have two small reactive forms set up:

```
    this.coordinatesForm = new FormGroup({
      latitude: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.min(-90), Validators.max(90)]),
      longitude: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.min(-180), Validators.max(180),]),
    });

    this.nameForm = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(28)]),
    });
```

When you click on 'Edit name', the first form should be dynamically inserted into the form on the dialog that pops up, and same thing for the coordinates. However, since the form groups are objects, I cannot iterate over the form controls in the dialog view. How can I best do this? Here's what I have in the dialog view:

```
    <mat-form-field appearance="legacy" *ngFor="let control of form.controls">
        <mat-label>??</mat-label> 
        <input matInput formControlName="control.name" placeholder="??" />
    </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Not sure it helps your use case, but the `keyvalue` pipe allows object properties to be iterated in the template.

Comment: thanks, looking for how to iterate over them in the view to begin with since formgroup is an object

Comment: Someone asked a similar question a few weeks ago, but now I can't find it. Anyway, the shortfall with trying to iterate over the form controls is that you then lose any ability to format the label. What are you going to put where `??` is? The form control name? Also, are all of the inputs of the same type?  I don't think you can reasonably do what you're trying to do without relying on an external data structure.